# Reload config apache with puppet in vagrant

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I set it up a vagrant machine with https://puphpet.com/#.

Everything was OK until I wanted to change the documentroot for an apache vhost:docroot in config.yaml

This change is not reloaded although I run :

```
vagrant --provision reload
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run `$ vagrant provision`, no need to reload.